# How to find a random ID on HTML page (Cucumber/Capybara)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to test an application that generate tickets, so I have to open a ticket and then assume it. 
I'm having a problem with the part of assume it, because the tickets are opened with a random ID (the number of the ticket).

```
<button type="submit" id="assign_ticket_6168218" class="btn btn-primary exchange_button">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Assume
```

The number of `id="assign_ticket_6168218"` is random, but the other part is always the same. 
So, I'm creating the ticket and now I have to click on the button to assume it. How can I create a ticket and store the number of the ticket to use it on the ID?

PS: If this is importante, when a create the ticket, I receive a  confirmation message with the ticket's ID:

```
`<div id="messages" class="clearfix">
  <div class="success global alert-default form-section">
   <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Ticket 6168218 created.</li>
  </ul>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="close-alert"><strong>x</strong></a>
 </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already extracted the ticket number into a variable (from your previous question on SO), then it's just

```
click_button("assign_ticket_#{ticket_number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath search, instead of a css find to get the element on which you want to test.  xpath supports regex so it could be something like

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//div[contains(@cid, 'assign_ticket_')]")
```

Or, if you have the number ( the ticket number in your case ) that has been created, you could do

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//div[contains(@cid, 'assign_ticket_#{ticket_object_number')]")
```

Comment: I tried this form but doesn't worked. Them I tried this `page.find(:xpath, "//div[contains(@cid, 'assign_ticket_#{@ticket_no[1]}')]")`. But I'm receiving a message that is not found `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//div[contains(@cid, 'assign_ticket_6168332')]"`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably mean @id in your XPath. Also CSS supports matching attributes that begin/end/contain strings too -   div[id*="assign_ticket_"]  would do a contains match just like the XPath provided, and div[id^="assign_ticket_"] would do a starts-with match on the id